# I want to retrieve the contact photo from the phone contacts. How should i proceed with getting the contact photo?

Tags: java, android

I am using the code below to access the phone numbers and the names of the contact. I want to add to this function a way to also add the photo of the contact.

```
void loadContacts() {
    ContentResolver contentResolver=getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor=contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,null);
    if(cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            int hasPhoneNumber = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)));
            if (hasPhoneNumber > 0) {
                Cursor cursor2 = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{id}, null);
                while (cursor2.moveToNext()) {
                    String phoneNumber = cursor2.getString(cursor2.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
//make_contact() is a function that takes the contact details and adds them to a list
//                        make_contact(name,phoneNumber);
                }
                cursor2.close();
            }
        }
    }
    cursor.close();
}
```

Comment: just check this out https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.html

Answer (score 0):

This is the sample Activity Assume the Appropriate XML is there.

package com.example;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = MyActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_PICK_CONTACTS = 1;
    private Uri uriContact;
    private String contactID;     // contacts unique ID


    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    public void onClickSelectContact(View btnSelectContact) {

        // using native contacts selection
        // Intent.ACTION_PICK = Pick an item from the data, returning what was selected.
        startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI), REQUEST_CODE_PICK_CONTACTS);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PICK_CONTACTS && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Response: " + data.toString());
            uriContact = data.getData();

            retrieveContactName();
            retrieveContactNumber();
            retrieveContactPhoto();

        }
    }

    private void retrieveContactPhoto() {

        Bitmap photo = null;

        try {
            InputStream inputStream = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(getContentResolver(),
                    ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, new Long(contactID)));

            if (inputStream != null) {
                photo = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_contact);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
            }

            assert inputStream != null;
            inputStream.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void retrieveContactNumber() {

        String contactNumber = null;

        // getting contacts ID
        Cursor cursorID = getContentResolver().query(uriContact,
                new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts._ID},
                null, null, null);

        if (cursorID.moveToFirst()) {

            contactID = cursorID.getString(cursorID.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        }

        cursorID.close();

        Log.d(TAG, "Contact ID: " + contactID);

        // Using the contact ID now we will get contact phone number
        Cursor cursorPhone = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER},

                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " +
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE + " = " +
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE,

                new String[]{contactID},
                null);

        if (cursorPhone.moveToFirst()) {
            contactNumber = cursorPhone.getString(cursorPhone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        }

        cursorPhone.close();

        Log.d(TAG, "Contact Phone Number: " + contactNumber);
    }

    private void retrieveContactName() {

        String contactName = null;

        // querying contact data store
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uriContact, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

            // DISPLAY_NAME = The display name for the contact.
            // HAS_PHONE_NUMBER =   An indicator of whether this contact has at least one phone number.

            contactName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
        }

        cursor.close();

        Log.d(TAG, "Contact Name: " + contactName);

    }
}
```